# Диапазон дат в jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Использую в проекте jquery datepicker с параметрами

```
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
```

При выборе года показывается только 10 ближайших например по умолчанию стоит сегодняшняя дата и соответственно 2020 год, в списке будет диапазон от 2010 года 2020. Возможно ли сделать так чтобы был диапазон от более раннего например 1960, либо чтобы в списке был полный диапазон от 1960 до 2010

Answer (score 2):

Решение было найдено в файле jquery-ui.js . Достаточно изменить параметры

```
        changeYear: false, 
        yearRange: "c-10:c+10",
```

На:

```
        changeYear: true, 
        yearRange: "c-60:c+0",
```

Может кому-то будет полезно